# jQuery UI Datepicker, setting the minDate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the jQuery UI datepicker to fill in two fields in a form. The initial text in the date fields is "Arrival Date" and "Departure Date", and my intention is for the text to disappear when the field comes into focus. The html for the form is

```
<form action="/book/book1.php" method="post" target="_blank" id="bookboxform" name="bookboxform">
<input name="ArrivalDate" id="ArrivalDate" value="Arrival Date">
<input name="DepartureDate" id="DepartureDate" value="Departure Date"> 
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="document.bookboxform.submit()" class="buttonBook">Enquire or Book</a>
</form>
```

Then the jQuery code to make it all happen is

```
$("#ArrivalDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "d M yy",
        minDate: 0,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onClose: function () {
            var DepDate = $('#DepartureDate');
            var limitDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            //add 1 day to Arrival Date
            limitDate.setDate(limitDate.getDate() + 1);
            DepDate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', limitDate);
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        }
    });
    $('#DepartureDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "d M yy",
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true
    });
```

This works, but having used the datepicker to select an arrival date, the text has disappeared from the departure date input field. I would like the text "Departure Date" to stay there until the cursor is placed in the box.

I have found that deleting the line

```
DepDate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', limitDate);
```

overcomes the problem, but introduces a new one: it is now possible to enter a departure date before the arrival date.

Is there any way I can get both the text to hang on in there and set the minDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code that sets minDate for the DepartureDate input to the `beforeShow` function of the DepartureDate datepicker.  I've also added the same functionality so if DepartureDate has a date in it, the ArrivalDate picker only shows days up to the day prior.

```
$("#ArrivalDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "d M yy",
    minDate: 0,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (Date.parse($('#DepartureDate').val())) {
            var maxDate = $('#DepartureDate').datepicker('getDate');
            maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - 1); //subtract a day
            $("#ArrivalDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxDate);
        }
    }

});

$('#DepartureDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "d M yy",
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    beforeShow: function () {
        var minDate = $('#ArrivalDate').datepicker('getDate');
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1); //add a day
        $("#DepartureDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);
    }
});
```

This is not code to cover every possible scenario to make sure that DepartureDate is later than Arrival date--it just solves the particular problem you posted about.  You can use the onClose function on both pickers to check if the other one contains an invalid date, and clear it if needed.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with some addition code to reset the other field if it has an invalid date.  This can happen if the user manually edits the field: https://jsfiddle.net/tonyhinkle/hup8n88s/

Comment: For relative simplicity I've gone for the version shown in the answer above. Thanks, Tony.